# Python ERROR:aiogram.dispatcher.dispatcher:Cause exception while getting updates

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiogram

I am making a Telegram bot with a PostgreSQL database. The bot is written in Python with the Aiogram library. Once in a while, an error appears in the console, which (as it seems to me) does not affect the operation of the script, but it constantly appears:

```
ERROR:aiogram.dispatcher.dispatcher:Cause exception while getting updates.
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/dispatcher/dispatcher.py", line 383, in start_polling
     updates = await self.bot.get_updates(
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/bot/bot.py", line 97, in get_updates
     result = await self.request(api.Methods.GET_UPDATES, payload)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/bot/base.py", line 208, in request
     return await api.make_request(self.session, self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiogram/bot/api.py", line 139, in make_request
     async with session.post(url, data=req, **kwargs) as response:
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1117, in __aenter__
     self._resp = await self._coro
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 544, in _request
     await resp.start(conn)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py", line 905, in start
     self._continue = None
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/helpers.py", line 656, in __exit__
     raise asyncio.TimeoutError from None
 asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError
```

Comment: The last line in the logs says it all. It's getting a TimeoutError. Maybe the server you're trying to connect has a throttling strategy to prevent requesting information too often.

Comment: @Leuofiridia okay, does this affect the script somehow? Or can this error be ignored? Just after about 1.5-2 days of work on the server, the script just stops and does nothing.

Comment: This depends exclusively on how you're handling connections on your script. Some APIs implement anti-replay strategies that may cause these errors. you'll need to review the contract between the api and your script.